# Redirecting URL with query parameters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, .htaccess

My URL is as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/yyy/#1234
```

By using this url, I get the numbers next to # which are "1234". Then I make some queries using Angular JS.

However, if user enters:

```
http://www.example.com/yyy/1234
```

it gives an 404 not found error. What I want to do is, if user enters the second url it should redirect to first url while keeping the numbers next to the hash. I don't use PHP, I parse the url using Javascript. I think it is possible by adding .htaccess code but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) will do what you want :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/yyy/(.+)$ /yyy/#$1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

The `NE` flag allows an unescaped `#`, the `R` flag gives the redirect code (you can use 301 if you prefer), the `L` flag avoids other rules to be applied (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html)).

If you have troubles with rewrite rules not matching your url (that happens all the time to me), you can activate the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2, [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4).

Comment: Try with `^yyy/(.+)$` as pattern. What does the rewrite log says ?